# identify_boot_cpu() crash in vmware

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, linux-kernel

I am getting a crash on `identify_boot_cpu` when I am trying to run boot an iso inside vmware.

What could be the reason of the crash at this location?

More info added:
I was booting a vmware with this: [pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd) and i got this: [pasteboard.co/H30KYya.png](http://pasteboard.co/H30KYya.png)

Comment: Logs, backtrace anything!! Or are you expecting people to read your mind and just find out what actually is happening?

Comment: :P,  I was booting a vmware with this: https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ 
and i got this: https://pasteboard.co/H30KYya.png

Comment: I am still confused. Are you trying to boot a Linux kernel on a VMWare player configured to run Windows 7?

Comment: Yes , you are correct , so but can i fix this? or can you tell me what can be the issue? what does this function does? and maybe i can fix this since the thing i am trying to boot from is open source.

Comment: Or shall I ask a ques "How to boot a linux kernel on vmware configured for windows". ?

Comment: Actually i thought it must be cake-walk for *nix experts!

Comment: You should ask this question on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).